# What pattern to use for Data Access in WPF/MVVM App

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql, design-patterns, data-access-layer

I have a task management application that currently uses a class to access data using Linq-to-SQL; I want to move the data access to a separate solution in the project. The reason I want to do this is in preparation for two things. First is to create a service that will run on the database "Server" (It is just a win 7 PC) that will periodically query tasks and send out email reminders for ones that are due. Second is to change data access to WCF so that I can access tasks from WP7 (Once they are on Verizon)

The tasks that are returned are defined by a number of user controls that are bound to a viewmodel. Currently an iQueryable is built up in a series of statements that narrow down the selection according to the databound members. Then the query is ordered by other members. Once I move the data access out of the solution so that it will not have access to the viewmodels members I will need to pass a relatively large number of parameters and I am not sure what the correct way to do this would be. The ways I can think of are:

1. Simply create a method with a dozen or more parameters (I am told this is bad practice)
2. Create an object that contains all the parameters and pass that (Doesn't seem much different that the first option to me)
3. Create a class in the data access solution, and then instantiate it and set each of its properties before calling a method that would return the iQueryable (or ObservableCollection) but I have read that this practice "smells bad"

I am pretty green at OOP and WPF and this simple app is the most complicated I have built. I feel like I am missing a pattern or practice, suggestions?

A sample of how the query is being built:

```
IQueryable<Issue> issuesQuery;

// Will select all items
issuesQuery = from i in db.Issues
      select i;

// Filters out pending issues
issuesQuery = issuesQuery.Where(i => i.IssIsPending == showPendingTasks);

// Filters out closed issues if they are not to be shown
if (includeClosedIssues == false) {
    issuesQuery = issuesQuery.Where(i => i.IssIsClosed == false);
}

// Filters out Regular Tasks if they are not to be shown
if (showTasks == false) {
    issuesQuery = from i in issuesQuery
             where i.IssIsOnStatusBoard == true
             select i;
}

// More filters are here

// Order the results      
issuesQuery = issuesQuery.OrderByDescending(
    i => i.IssIsSticky).ThenBy(
    i=>!i.IssDueDate.HasValue).ThenBy(
    i => i.IssDueDate).ThenBy(
    i => i.IssUrgency);

// an iQueryable is returned but is then converted to an ObservableCollection
return issuesQuery;
```

Comment: Actually the second point (an object with parameters) is better because: 1) you can add or remove parameters and method will be still compatible with other clients; 2) it is possible to set only necessary parameters and pass object with default values. But I haven't understood 3rd point, could you provide a code or link to an article, if it isn't much of a trouble for you? Also you can take a look on WCF Data Services, but they are not always better than common WCF services.

Comment: On the 3rd method I would create a public class with members for all the parameters and a method to return the Collection. To use it you would instantiate it, set all the members then call the method (Which would use the members' values to determine what items to return)

Comment: I just purchased John Sharps "Windows Communication Foundation 4" a couple weeks ago but was delayed in starting it due to a Birthday Kindle :) I know very little about it at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain you how to use Services, because they are mandatory in 3-tired architecture and separate a model from a view as nothing else can.

You can use two different solutions.

**1. WCF DataServices.**

Add -> New Item -> Wcf Data Service.

Then specify the name of the DataContext and set rights of access.

```
public class WcfDataService1 : DataService<TestEntities>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Example of custom operations
    /// </summary>
    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<Item> ItemsById(int id)
    {
        return this.CurrentDataSource.Items.Where(i => i.Id == id);
    }
}
```

In a client application add a new service reference and after that you can use the service as if it was a local database:

```
var proxy = new TestEntities(new Uri("http://localhost:8513/WcfDataService1.svc/"));
var items = proxy.Items.Where(i => i.Id > 2 && i.Title.Contains("x1"));
var item2 = proxy.Execute<Item>(new Uri("ItemsById?Id=1", UriKind.Relative)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Advantage: you don't need to write numerous methods like GetItemsById, GetItemsByYear, GetTenItems, etc; you can create a filter query on the client's side.

Disadvantages: service operations isn't statically typed; it's dificult to call custom operations especially if thay have many parameters; there are many problems if to use custom objects instead of entities;

**2. WCF Services**

Add -> New Item -> Wcf Service

Repository class:

```
public class IssuesRepository
{
    public static List<Issue> GetIssues()
    {
        //creating a new connection will not cause overhead because there is a pool of connections
        using (var db = new TestEntities()) 
        {
            List<Expression<Func<Issue, bool>>> filters = new List<Expression<Func<Issue, bool>>>();

            filers.Add(i => i.IssIsPending == showPendingTasks);

            if (includeClosedIssues == false)
                filers.Add(i => i.IssIsClosed == false);

            if (showTasks == false)
                filers.Add(i => i.IssIsOnStatusBoard == true);


            IQueryable<Issue> issuesQuery = db.Items.AsQueryable();

            foreach (var filter in filters)
                issuesQuery = issuesQuery.Where(filter);

            issuesQuery = from i in issuesQuery
                          orderby i.IssIsSticky descending, !i.IssDueDate.HasValue ascending, i.IssDueDate, i.IssUrgency
                          select i;

            return issuesQuery.ToList(); //it will be serialized in any case
        }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public List<Issue> GetIssues()
    {
        return IssuesRepository.GetIssues();
    }
}
```

Advantages: independent on protocol; provide sessions, security, transactions.

So as a conclusion I recommend to use DataServices if you need just a CRUD functionality, and common WCF services if you use a set of operations with complex logic.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the response. it looks like I have some homework to do.

Comment: @Mike B Just read the book and write a few test applications to be more familiar with WCF. After that many things will be simpler.